# Whether to perform an inner join or cross join to expand based on date range provided in another table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables.

DateTable1 (client-wise month start and end dates, an appropriate month number):
Client|MonthNumber|MonthStartDate|MonthEndDate

DateTable2 (1 row for each day, for each client, and the row holds an appropriare QuarterNumber):
Client|Date|QuarterNumber

I want to create 1 date table such that it has 1 row for each day, for each client showing the QuarterNumber (thus far it is the same as DateTable2), and additionally I want  the MonthNumber from DateTable1.

I am thinking about 2 solutions:

1. Perform an inner join on client name, and apply the where criteria to filter such that DateTable2's date is between the start and end values of DateTable1.
2. Perform cross join (so without an on clause), and apply the same where criteria as above.

Please can I have guidance on how to choose from the above solutions?

Comment: Is `MonthNumber` a client-specific concept or does it track dates in a reasonable way? If a client has no `DateTable1` rows for a particular `MonthNumber` what results do you expect?

Comment: There is always a row in DateTable1.

Comment: There is no difference between an INNER JOIN and a filtered CROSS JOIN.  Based on the description I would probably start with a CROSS JOIN, but there's no hard-and-fast rule here.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer here is likely to utilize a calendar table.

If you can't or don't want to fully implement one, you can fake one with a little recursion:

```
DECLARE @DateTable1 TABLE (Client INT, MonthNumber INT, MonthStartDate DATE, MonthEndDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @DateTable1 (Client, MonthNumber, MonthStartDate, MonthEndDate) VALUES
(1, 1, '2022-01-01', '2022-01-31'),(1, 2, '2022-02-01', '2022-02-28'),(1, 3, '2022-03-01', '2022-03-31'),(1, 4, '2022-04-01', '2022-04-30'),(1, 5, '2022-05-01', '2022-05-31'),
(2, 1, '2022-01-01', '2022-01-31'),(2, 2, '2022-02-01', '2022-02-28'),(2, 3, '2022-03-01', '2022-03-31'),(2, 4, '2022-04-01', '2022-04-30'),                            
(3, 1, '2022-01-01', '2022-01-31'),(3, 2, '2022-02-01', '2022-02-28'),(3, 3, '2022-03-01', '2022-03-31'),(3, 4, '2022-04-01', '2022-04-30'),(3, 5, '2022-05-01', '2022-05-31'),(3, 6, '2022-06-01', '2022-06-30');

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT Client, MIN(MonthNumber) AS mnS, MAX(MonthNumber) AS mnE, MIN(MonthStartDate) AS Date, DATEPART(QUARTER,MIN(MonthStartDate)) AS Quarter
  FROM @DateTable1
 GROUP BY Client
UNION ALL
SELECT Client, mnS, mnE, DATEADD(DAY,1,Date) AS Date, DATEPART(QUARTER,DATEADD(DAY,1,Date)) AS Quarter 
  FROM cte
 WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,1,Date)) <= mnE
)

SELECT Client, Date, Quarter
  FROM cte
 ORDER BY Client, Date
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Using just one of you tables we can iterate over the dates that should be available for your clients, and fill in the gaps.

```
Client  Date        Quarter
---------------------------
1       2022-01-01  1
1       2022-01-02  1
1       2022-01-03  1
...
1       2022-05-30  2
1       2022-05-31  2
2       2022-01-01  1
2       2022-01-02  1
...
2       2022-04-29  2
2       2022-04-30  2
3       2022-01-01  1
3       2022-01-02  1
...
3       2022-06-29  2
3       2022-06-30  2
```

Each client now has a row for each day (where they have data in the first table).
You can join to this as necessary.

Edit:

if the other table is as described and contains a non-standard quarter number you could just join to it:

```
DECLARE @DateTable1 TABLE (Client INT, MonthNumber INT, MonthStartDate DATE, MonthEndDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @DateTable1 (Client, MonthNumber, MonthStartDate, MonthEndDate) VALUES
(1, 1, '2022-01-01', '2022-01-31'),(1, 2, '2022-02-01', '2022-02-28'),(1, 3, '2022-03-01', '2022-03-31'),(1, 4, '2022-04-01', '2022-04-30'),(1, 5, '2022-05-01', '2022-05-31'),
(2, 1, '2022-01-01', '2022-01-31'),(2, 2, '2022-02-01', '2022-02-28'),(2, 3, '2022-03-01', '2022-03-31'),(2, 4, '2022-04-01', '2022-04-30'),                            
(3, 1, '2022-01-01', '2022-01-31'),(3, 2, '2022-02-01', '2022-02-28'),(3, 3, '2022-03-01', '2022-03-31'),(3, 4, '2022-04-01', '2022-04-30'),(3, 5, '2022-05-01', '2022-05-31'),(3, 6, '2022-06-01', '2022-06-30');

DECLARE @DataTable2 TABLE (Client INT, Date DATE, QuarterNumber INT)
INSERT INTO @DataTable2 (Client, Date, QuarterNumber) VALUES

(1, '2022-01-01', 1),(1, '2022-01-02', 1),(1, '2022-01-03', 1),(1, '2022-01-04', 1),
(1, '2022-05-30', 2),(1, '2022-05-31', 2),(2, '2022-01-01', 1),(2, '2022-01-02', 1),
(2, '2022-01-03', 1),(2, '2022-04-29', 2),(2, '2022-04-30', 2),(3, '2022-01-01', 3),
(3, '2022-01-02', 3),(3, '2022-01-03', 3),(3, '2022-06-28', 4),(3, '2022-06-29', 4),
(3, '2022-06-30', 4)

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT Client, MIN(MonthNumber) AS mnS, MAX(MonthNumber) AS mnE, MIN(MonthStartDate) AS Date, DATEPART(QUARTER,MIN(MonthStartDate)) AS Quarter
  FROM @DateTable1
 GROUP BY Client
UNION ALL
SELECT Client, mnS, mnE, DATEADD(DAY,1,Date) AS Date, DATEPART(QUARTER,DATEADD(DAY,1,Date)) AS Quarter 
  FROM cte
 WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,1,Date)) <= mnE
)

SELECT c.Client, c.Date, d.QuarterNumber
  FROM cte c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @DataTable2 d
      ON c.Client = d.Client
      AND c.Date = d.Date
 ORDER BY Client, Date
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I did not include every date from the other table.

Comment: The QuarterNumber value is in DateTable2, and this varies by client

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to join to the second table.